# App can't find requried certificates when runs under SYSTEM

Tags: windows, permissions, user-accounts, certificate

My app seeks for its required certificates in the windows certificate store (LocalMachine/TrustedPeople). The certificates were imported under Administrator account. The app runs fine until I start it under Local System account - it simply can't find the certificates.

Should I grant some permissions to Local System? How can I do it?

Comment: Install the certificate to the machine certificate store not the user's

Comment: @Ramhound, it's already installed there (LocalMachine/TrustedPeople)